# Embedding a Jar into a C# Form

Tags: c#, java, forms, jar, wrapper

Ok this situation is a bit difficult. But I am trying to embed a Java Jar into a C# form. Not as a new window or new process.

The Jar will be a game that uses the LWJGL library.

The C# Form will be a "wrapper" for it with tools and more.

Anyone have any ideas? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [IKVM Home Page](http://www.ikvm.net/)

> IKVM.NET is an implementation of Java
>   for Mono and the Microsoft .NET
>   Framework. It includes the following
>   components:
>
> A Java Virtual Machine implemented in
>   .NET A .NET implementation of the Java
>   class libraries Tools that enable Java
>   and .NET interoperability

Comment: Welcome... didn't know about it till a few weeks ago... stumbled on it by chance. Glad could help out :D

Answer (score 0):

One would approach it from using a DLL not a jar.  Also this sounds like a bit of a security issue.

Comment: I'm not using the Jar like a lib

Answer (score 0):

They're completely different runtimes; you'll need a process for both the CLR and the JVM; no way around that.

You can try the Java to C# converter provided by MS, and then rebuild: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=46bea47e-d47f-4349-9b4f-904b0a973174&displaylang=en